# How i can convert string values in formats "1.123" and "1,123" to double by single double.TryParse?

Tags: c#, .net, string, double, typeconverter

I have an incoming source of string values representing double values with "." and "," delimiter and my program would run on PCs with different settings of delimiter ("," or ",")
Which way can I convert it with single line without trying first convert ".", then if fail, try ","?
I tried some combinations like that:

```
    string dot_val = "1.12";
    string non_dot_val = "1,12";

    double dot_double = 0, non_dot_double = 0;

    bool dot_res = double.TryParse(dot_val, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out dot_double);
    bool non_dot_res = double.TryParse(non_dot_val, NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out non_dot_double);
```

But one of the attempts to convert is always fail.
If tell it shortly, I need an universal function to convert "." or "," delimited double values into double

Comment: How about `dot_val = not_dot_val.Replace(',', '.');` ?

Comment: it will fail if PC settings set that delimiter is ,

Comment: Then get the delimiter from PC setting and replace like not_dot_val.Replace(',', PC Delimiter)

Comment: The main problem here is that the data is ambiguous. 1,123 can mean 1123 (one thousand, one hundred and twenty three) or 1.123 (one point one two three), depending on what culture you interpret it in. The same goes for 1.123. It will mean 1123 in German and most other European cultures, but it will mean 1.123 in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to replace ',' by '.' and parse the result using the invariant culture setting:

```
double.TryParse(
          dot_val.Replace(',','.'), 
          NumberStyles.Any, 
          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
          out dot_double);
```

The only limitation of this is that you shouldn't have grouping in your number (like 123,000.45)

Comment: It that so? What if I gave you this: 1,000.50?

Comment: That's not an actual use case of the OP, but you're right. Your solution has the same problem though :)

Comment: Your solution fails for 1,234. The resulting number will be 1234

Comment: since i am not planning to give it values like "123,000.45" i think it's good one :P Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Well, the current culture tells you whether `.` or `,` is the decimal separator. If you want your function to parse both formats, you need to pass in a culture that has the respective separator. In your example:

```
public double UniveralParse(string value)
{
    double result;

    // If we can not parse the "." format...
    if (!double.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), out result))
        // And also can not parse the "," format...
        if (!double.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"), out result))
            // we throw an exception
            throw new ArgumentException("value is not in expected format!");

    // Otherwise we can return the value
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This will fail for "100,000" or "1,123" if the number was supposed to be 100 or 1.123

Comment: I was looking for a single line way :P Without much checks what failed and what no. I need to convert a lot of this values and should do it fast